# Get a gzip sitemap in nodejs

Tags: node.js, axios, gzip, sitemap

Using axios to get a gzip sitemap from a third party

```
let response = await axios.get(`${url}/th-sitemapIndex.xml.gz`, {
 headers: {
   'Accept': '*/*',
   'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br'
 }
});
```

However I keep getting the below error:

> code:'Z_BUF_ERROR' message:'unexpected end of file' stack:'Error: unexpected end of file\n    at Zlib.zlibOnError [as onerror] (zlib.js:182:17)\n    at Zlib.callbackTrampoline (internal/async_hooks.js:126:14)'

The sitemap works fine in a browser or postman. Any ideas why its not working using axios?

I also was thinking about downloading the sitemap locally, unzipping and parsing it, but I don't need someone to guide me through the process

Comment: Can you provide the URL or the downloaded data?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the source is corrupted, and that the browser and postman are getting the same error but ignoring it.

Comment: Might be, I sent an email to the third party while checking for other possible solutions